# astronomical events have stopped occuring

Tags: kittens-game

I have not seen any astronomical events in a long time and I desperately need the starcharts! My observatories are NOT off, either! Is this fixable? Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: it has occurred to me that my observatories may be off, and i have absolutely no idea how to turn them back on, if they are. any help?

Comment: Observatories can't be turned off anymore, I believe.  Are you sure your starchart count isn't increasing?  If you've bought SETI I think it is, astronomical events happen in background (no log entry) and are automatically observed (science and starchart added).

Comment: oh goodness! this makes so much sense now. my starchart count is increasing, i was just so used to physically seeing every time an astronomical event happened that when i no longer saw them i thought they weren't happening, thank you for the help! (^:

Comment: Ah, well, I guess I'll make that an answer then.  I was sure that wasn't it, lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A late-game science upgrade, SETI, makes astronomical events automatically observed.  Since a bunch of spam about something you no longer need to worry about could get annoying, the developer also chose to have the SETI upgrade make astronomical events silent, meaning they no longer write to the log.

Your starchart continues to increase, and will do so faster the more observatories you have.  There are also some space upgrades that can give starcharts over time.